# MyPayroll3.java:44: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

```
public class MyPayroll3 {
   //Declare variable
   static String firstName, lastName, course;
   static String[] args = {};
   static double hourlyRate, stateTaxRate, federalTaxRate, ficaRate, stateTaxTotal, federalTaxTotal, ficaTotal, regularPay,overtimePay, grossPay, netPay;
   static int hoursWorked;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      getCommandLineArguments(args); 
      calculations();
   }

   public static void getCommandLineArguments(String [] args){
      //Assign command-line arguments to variables
      int k = args[0].indexOf(" ");
      firstName = args[0].substring(0,k); 
      lastName  = args[0].substring(k + 1);
      course = args[1];
      hoursWorked = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
      hourlyRate = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
      stateTaxRate = Double.parseDouble(args[4]);
      federalTaxRate = Double.parseDouble(args[5]);
      ficaRate = Double.parseDouble(args[6]);
   }   

   //Calculate taxes and income
   public static void calculations() { 
      stateTaxTotal = grossPay - (grossPay*stateTaxRate);
      federalTaxTotal = grossPay - (grossPay*federalTaxRate);
      ficaTotal = grossPay - (grossPay*ficaRate); 
      double taxes = stateTaxTotal + federalTaxTotal + ficaTotal;
      regularPay = (hoursWorked * hourlyRate) - overtimePay;
      overtimePay = (hoursWorked % 40) * hourlyRate(1.5);
      grossPay = regularPay + overtimePay;
      netPay = grossPay - taxes;
   }


}
```

The problem is at the bottom line that starts with "overtimePay =". It says "cannot find symbol' and points to hourlyRate. I've made it a global variable and i dont know what to do now.

Comment: Where do you define `hourlyRate()`? Also what is the full stacktrace

Comment: hourlyRate is a double, not a method.

Comment: Did you mean to do: `overtimePay = (hoursWorked % 40) * hourlyRate * 1.5;` ?

Comment: Your code is quite long and there is no error shown. Next time, please provide a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a method named `hourlyRate`.  If you place parentheses after an identifier, the compiler assumes it's a method, passing `1.5` to it, not a multiplication by 1.5.

If you intend to multiply by 1.5, normal mathematical notation of including a number in parentheses does not work; the multiplication operator `*` must be explicit.

Change

```
overtimePay = (hoursWorked % 40) * hourlyRate(1.5);
```

to

```
overtimePay = (hoursWorked % 40) * hourlyRate * 1.5;
```

To account for `hoursWorked` being at least 80, you may want to just subtract 40 from `hoursWorked`, instead of using the mod operator.